# Add and remove delegates by using Microsoft Graph (Outlook REST API)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am looking for the following equivalent: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641959(v=exchg.150).aspx ("How to: Add and remove delegates by using EWS in Exchange")

Is this already on Microsoft Graph? (didn't see on the /beta endpoint that sports the Outlook REST API) If it is not today, is this in the near future? (delegating access to calendar / mails /... is quite common in company settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we don't support this via the REST APIs today. Definitely a good feature to have though. You should post it on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ so folks can vote it up :)

Comment: Done. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/30973693-add-and-remove-delegates-by-using-microsoft-graph